# How to prevent react-navigation to animate the height of the AppBar when changing views?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-paper

I  see the Android AppBar animating it's `height` while changing pages.

This is my `AppBar.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Appbar as AppBarDefault } from 'react-native-paper';
import Logo from '../Logo';

const {
  Header,
  BackAction,
  Content,
  Action,
} = AppBarDefault;

export default class AppBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { nav, pages, previous } = this.props;
    return (
      <Header statusBarHeight={Constants.statusBarHeight}>
        {previous ? (
          <BackAction onPress={() => nav.goBack()} />
        ) : (
          <Action
            icon="menu"
            onPress={nav.openDrawer}
          />
        )}
        <Content
          title={<Logo />}
          style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
        />
        <Action icon="account-supervisor-circle" onPress={() => nav.navigate(pages.list)} />
      </Header>
    );
  }
}
```

Is this the default behavior and can I prevent that?

I have also tried to use:

```
    <Stack.Navigator {...getStackConfig(routes)} screenOptions={screenOptions}>
      {routes.map((route) => (
        <Stack.Screen
          key={route.path}
          name={route.page}
          component={route.component}
          options={{
            title: route.message,
            headerStyleInterpolator: HeaderStyleInterpolators.forFade,
            headerStyle: {
              height: Constants.statusBarHeight + REACT_PAPER_APPBAR_HEIGHT
            },
            ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

This enable slide from right (ios style), I hope it could solve the AppBar animation but I still have the animation of two AppBar while I want no animation on AppBar.

Is there a way to disable all AppBar animation on android ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change `cardStyleInterpolator` in `screenOptions`:

Default for android is `forRevealFromBottomAndroid` you can changed it to others options:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
  cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS // what ever you want 
}}>
...
</Stack.Navigator>
```

More options: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#cardstyleinterpolators